# OpenStreetMap offline?

Tags: offline, openstreetmap

I use OpenStreetMap on my side, but it works through their page. I wonder if it is possible to download some of the map and use the local server. So far I have found something like this:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/offline-storage.html

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/offline-storage.js

But here are using the cache.

Answer (score 22):

Of course this is possible, OpenStreetMap's data is free and so are most of the tools around it.

For rendering your own [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) just follow the steps described on [switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/) in the [serving tiles](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) guide. You can also import one of the [extracts](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Extract#Country_and_area_extracts) if you don't want to serve the whole planet. Alternatively you can use some of the other available [renderers and toolchains](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Renderer) for creating your own tiles, for example [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) and [TileMill](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill).

If you are interested in routing then take a look at the [routing wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) and especially at the list of various [online routers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/OnlineRouters) and [offline routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) for OSM.

For geocoding there are various [search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) available of which [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) is the most popular one at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

With marble you can download regions of the selected map. Marble also has an interesting list of downloadable maps. Some OSM based: roads, cycle map and satellite as well as historical maps and other.

On linux+macOS+windows: Marble. 
`sudo yum install marble`
 or 
`sudo apt-get install marble`
 e.t.c.

"Marble is a virtual globe and world atlas — your swiss army knife for maps."
Offline mode, download maps. Browse map. Select view/data source. Routing. Search. 
https://marble.kde.org/ 
https://marble.kde.org/features.php

Many various other applications:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop

Comment: Marble needs Internet access for fetching tiles. It has a local tile cache for already visited tiles, though.

Comment: With marble you can download regions of the selected map. Marble also has an interesting list of downloadable maps. Some OSM based: roads, cycle map and satellite as well as historical maps and other.

Comment: Excactly what I looked for. For completness: this functionality is also available with `foxtrotgps`.

Comment: And for more completeness on Android there are a few apps but "Viewranger GPS" is good(/best!?) offering download/cache from free maps like OSM, and OpenCycleMap(good map for hiking with contours).