# Offline Maps in Windows Desktop Application

Tags: c#, maps, desktop-application, offline

I want to develop a desktop application that will have offline maps. It is pertinent to mention that application will work without an internet connection. Please tell me in which format, maps to be downloaded and how to import those maps in application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenStreetMap offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735001/openstreetmap-offline)

Answer (score 0):

I recently did extensive web searching, and almost every major provider of maps handles offline usage, as long as you can connect for download at least once. HERE, Google, ESRI, OpenStreetMaps,etc.